# Dynamic explosion with specific character

Tags: php, explode

I am trying to extract a string in php and convert them to comma separated strings

Here are some sample string I am working with and the results I need:

input :

```
 G1_C2_S3_T5  or  G4_C5_S4_T7_I6_H3
```

Result must be :

```
  G1,G1_C2,G1_C2_S3,G1_C2_S3_T5

  or

  G4,G4_C5,G4_C5_S4,G4_C5_S4_T7,G4_C5_S4_T7_I6,G4_C5_S4_T7_I6_H3
```

Input length can be dynamic for comma separation

Is this correct :

```
  $arr = explode("_", $string, 2);
  $first = $arr[0];
```

How can i do that in php?

Comment: What did you already tried? Provide your own attempts to solve this task. Stack Overflow is not for "write code for me" kinds of questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work, `$string` is the string you are working with

```
//explode by underscore
$parts = explode('_', $string);

$c = [];
//do until nothing else to pop from array
while (!empty($parts)) {
    $c[] = implode('_', $parts);
   //will pop element from end of array
    array_pop($parts);
}
//reverse 
$c = array_reverse($c);
//glue it with comma
echo implode(',', $c);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should notice that the number of underscore-separated values in your initial string e.g. `G4_C5_S4_T7_I6_H3` (6) is equal to the number of comma-separated values in your desired string e.g. `G4,G4_C5,G4_C5_S4,G4_C5_S4_T7,G4_C5_S4_T7_I6,G4_C5_S4_T7_I6_H3` (6). So we'll use this number in our first loop `$end = count($parts)`.

```
$str = "G4_C5_S4_T7_I6_H3";
$newstr = '';

$parts = explode('_', $str);
$comma = '';

for ($i = 0, $end = count($parts); $i < $end; $i++) {
    $newstr .= $comma;

    $underscore = '';
    // build underscore-separated value
    // index i is used to indicate up which value to stop at for each iteration
    for ($j = 0; $j <= $i; $j++) {
        $newstr .= $underscore . $parts[$j];
        // set underscore after the first iteration of the loop
        $underscore = '_';
    }
    // set comma after the first iteration of the loop
    $comma = ',';
}

echo $newstr; // G4,G4_C5,G4_C5_S4,G4_C5_S4_T7,G4_C5_S4_T7_I6,G4_C5_S4_T7_I6_H3
```

Answer (score 1):

The explosion is easy:

```
$parts = explode('_', $string);
```

Now you get a `$parts` array like `[ 'G1', 'C2', 'S3', 'T5' ]`.

You want to convert this to an array so that each item is the concatenation of that item and every other item before it:

```
$prev  = [ ];
array_walk(
    $parts,
    function(&$value) use (&$prev) {
        $prev[] = $value;
        $value  = implode('_', $prev);
    }
);
```

Now `$parts` holds the elements:

```
print implode(', ', $parts);
```

yields

```
G1, G1_C2, G1_C2_S3, G1_C2_S3_T5
```